# Validate property to be a sublclass of an abstract class in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, validation, oop

I'm brand new to OOP in Matlab, and still fairly green when it comes to OOP in general, but what I do know I learnt in C++.

I'm following the Matlab documentation found here [Property class and size validation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-size-and-class-validation.html#bvklfs7-1). I want to validate a property so that it must be a specific class and I'm using the example from the link. This is what my class looks like:

```
classdef simpoint
   ...
   properties
      ...
      outputType dataType
      ...
   end
   ...
end
```

In my code `dataType` is a class I've written. What's more it's abstract.

I'm getting the error

```
Error defining property 'outputType' of class 'simpoint':
Class dataType is abstract. Specify a default value for property outputType.
```

The class `dataType` is abstract to force the user to implement some methods. I'm trying to use property validation to make sure when `outputType` is set, the class is a subclass of `dataType`.

I don't really want to set a default value, because forgetting to set `outputType` should throw an error.

How can I validate `outputType` to make sure it is a subclass of `dataType`? Is there a better way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a more elegant solution to this problem, which is apparently not well known.

MATLAB has a concept of [Heterogeneous Class Hierarchies](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/heterogeneous-arrays.html). This is just fancy way of explicitly declaring the common root class (abstract or not) so that it *can* be used for property validation. In practice, all you need to do is to make your abstract class inherit from `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`.

Here is a quick example:

```matlab
classdef (Abstract) AbstractItem < handle & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
end
```

```matlab
classdef Collection < handle
    properties
        items AbstractItem
    end
end
```

Then you have no problem:

```
>> x = Collection

x = 

  Collection with properties:

    items: [0×0 AbstractItem]
```

Without the `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` inheritance you would get an error like you described:

> Error defining property 'items' of class 'Collection'. Class AbstractItem is abstract. Specify a default value for property items.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. I've marked it as the accepted one because it is much more elegant as you say. In fact, a year or so after asking the question, this is the method I found myself naturally using!

Comment: I spent a good few hours searching around the Internet and found many posts from people experiencing the very same problem, but no real solution existed. I found out about the Heterogeneous class after speaking with MathWorks engineers, and I felt compelled to publish this finding somewhere. This topic seemed to be a good place :)

Answer (score 2):

Your current code uses the following logic:

1. Create a new `simpoint` object
2. Ah this object needs an `outputType` property
3. Initialise the `outputType` property to be an empty `dataType` object
4. Uhoh, we can't instantiate an abstract object - error.

Instead, you could also use setters and getters to validate data types. This removes steps 3 and 4 above, since the initial property value will be `[]`.

```
classdef simpoint < matlab.mixin.SetGet
    properties
        outputType
    end
    methods 
        % ...
    end
    methods % Setters and getters
        function set.outputType( obj, v )
            % When the 'obj.outputType = X' is called, this function is
            % triggered. We can validate the input first
            assert( isa( v, 'dataType' ) );
            % If the assertion didn't error, we can set the property
            obj.outputType = v;
        end
        function v = get.outputType( obj )
            % Nothing bespoke in the getter (no not strictly needed), just return the value
            v = obj.outputType;
        end
    end
end
```

For more informative validation, you could use `validateattributes` instead of `assert`.

In this case, the default value of `outputType` will be `[]` unless you initialise it in the constructor.

Note, by using `matlab.mixin.SetGet` to enable setters and getters, I've implicitly made your object a `handle`. In broader OOP terms, the object is now accessed "by reference" rather than "by value". Read more [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html).

If you don't want a handle then you can remove the `< matlab.mixin.SetGet` and, by your own comment, define the setter more explicitly

```
function obj = set.outputType( obj, v )
    % Have to return 'obj' if the class isn't a handle.
    % ...
end
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help. So, is there any reason I can't write a method `SetOutputType(obj, v)` and not inherit from `matlab.mixin.SetGet`, rather than use `set.outputType(obj, v)` like you've defined here? Is it better practice to use `matlab.mixin.SetGet` ?

Comment: Your object has a property `outputType`. My way, you set this by using `thing.outputType = X`, and access it using `Y = thing.outputType`, with optional validation built in. To use a non-native setter (like your comment suggests), you would have to make the property `private`, otherwise the user could set it without using the `SetOutputType`, then you also likely need a public `GetOutputType`, and now the user knows that `outputType` is a property but can only access it through these helper functions which might be unknown? So just an ease of use and consistency improvement my way I think...

Comment: I don't know if I've not been clear - the `set.` and `get.` are called implicitly. Making the assignment `thing.outputType = X` now automatically calls `set( thing, 'outputType', X )`, which triggers the setter function, and therefore the validation.

Comment: This got me to the correct answer, but it is only valid if `simpoint` is a handle. If `simpoint` is a regular class then you need to use `obj = set.outputType( obj, v )`

Comment: @Phill - this is not true. Getters and setters work fine with normal classes. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html

Comment: @Cris, I see the confusion now I've booted up MATLAB... Please see the end of my edit. That syntax isn't required to call the setter, but it is required in the function definition.

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect they'd introduce inconsistent syntax like that. As you can see, I don't have much experience with handle classes. I should have tried that out before commenting... :/

Comment: @Cris it makes sense when you think about what's happening... for a value class we need to return the object, because it isn't linked by address - essentially like outputting a copy with the updated properties. For a handle we edit the referred-to object in memory, so no need to output it as any references are updated directly. That's how I think about it anyway.

Comment: I'm reading up a bit about the mixins. The [`matlab.mixin.SetGet`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.setget-class.html) class adds `set` and `get` functions. Basically it allows you to do `set(obj,'property',value)`. It is not necessary to enable the `obj.property=value` syntax nor the `get.property`/`set.property` class methods.